# How to make the height of div containers equal to each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the height of `div` elements with `col-lg-3` equal to each other. Now some of them are higher than the others.

As a stylesheet I am using `bootstrap.css`.

```
<!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h2 class="page-header">
                            Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla?
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">77.8% (112500)</div>
                                        <div>Bla-bla-bla</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="d3/pic.jpg">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-red">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">1.65% (XXX)</div>
                                        <div>Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="d3/piv.jpg">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix">   </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">XXX</div>
                                        <div>Bla-bla-bla.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-red">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">XXX</div>
                                        <div>Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I tried to add `display: flex;` to `.row` in `bootstrap.css`, but it does not help:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate. I tried the solutions proposed in the referenced thread including the one given in the fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/nV3Ua/1/`. Noen of them works for my case. Maybe that's because there are many nested `div` elements.